# Стилизация конкретного ScrollBar

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Возможно ли стилизовать ScrollBar у определённого элемента?
К примеру я открываю на сайте модальное окно и чтобы в нём скролл отличался от того, который прокручивает саму страницу.

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли стилизовать ScrollBar у определённого элемента?

да, возможно.

### однако

стоит учитывать особенности КАДОГО браузера КАЖДОЙ версии.
там обсуждают лиса:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/6165472/4794368

код ниже, проверялся в FF последней версии.
[взят оттуда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars)

```css
#qql {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}

body {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="qql">
q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>q<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно менять стили с помощью ::-webkit-scrollbar

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container" id="custom-scrolbar">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 65px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.content{
    min-height: 450px;
}

#custom-scrolbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#custom-scrolbar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#custom-scrolbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
                                       left bottom,
                                       left top,
                                       color-stop(0.44, rgb(122,153,217)),
                                       color-stop(0.72, rgb(73,125,189)),
                                       color-stop(0.86, rgb(28,58,148)));
}
```